# Invalid Pointer Operation + Runtime Error with custom drawing

Tags: delphi, timer, drawing, delphi-7

I'm working on a simple little app which has 1 image and 3 timers. The goal is to draw a number of balls chasing back and forth with a decaying color after each one. It looks something like this:

[image: Preview of program running]

Now the problem is when I close the application, I get a number of errors in this order, and does not give me a breakpoint in the code. It only happens when it's moving from the right to the left, not from the left to the right. I thought it probably had to do with the timer(s) continuing after the app closed, so I disabled the timers in the `OnClose` event - but still no luck.

[image: Invalid Pointer Operation (1)]

[image: Invalid Pointer Operation (2)]

[image: Runtime Error 217]

Here's the DFM code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 379
  Top = 631
  Width = 696
  Height = 254
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Img: TImage
    Left = 16
    Top = 56
    Width = 649
    Height = 15
  end
  object tmrDraw: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    Interval = 50
    OnTimer = tmrDrawTimer
    Left = 88
    Top = 128
  end
  object tmrBalls: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    Interval = 50
    OnTimer = tmrBallsTimer
    Left = 128
    Top = 128
  end
  object tmrChase: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    Interval = 60
    OnTimer = tmrChaseTimer
    Left = 168
    Top = 128
  end
end
```

And here's the source code:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, Math;

type
  TBallStates = array of Integer;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Img: TImage;
    tmrDraw: TTimer;
    tmrBalls: TTimer;
    tmrChase: TTimer;
    procedure tmrDrawTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tmrBallsTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tmrChaseTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    fPos: Integer;
    fDir: Integer;
    fBalls: TBallStates;
    fBallCount: Integer;
    fBMin: Integer;
    fBMax: Integer;
    fBStep: Integer;
    fCMin: TColor;
    fCMax: TColor;
  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function ColorBetween(const ColorA, ColorB: TColor; const Percent: Single): TColor;
var
  R1, G1, B1: Byte;
  R2, G2, B2: Byte;
begin
  R1:= GetRValue(ColorA);
  G1:= GetGValue(ColorA);
  B1:= GetBValue(ColorA);
  R2:= GetRValue(ColorB);
  G2:= GetGValue(ColorB);
  B2:= GetBValue(ColorB);
  Result:= RGB(
    EnsureRange(Round(R1*Percent + R2*(100-Percent) / 100), 0, 255),
    EnsureRange(Round(G1*Percent + G2*(100-Percent) / 100), 0, 255),
    EnsureRange(Round(B1*Percent + B2*(100-Percent) / 100), 0, 255)
  );
end;

//This timer sets the intensities of the balls
procedure TForm1.tmrBallsTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;   //Loop counter
  C: Integer;   //Count of balls
  V: Integer;   //Value of individual ball intensity
begin
  C:= Length(fBalls);
  for X:= 0 to C - 1 do begin
    V:= fBalls[X];    
    if (V >= fBMin - fBStep - 1) and (V <= fBMin + fBStep + 1) then begin
      V:= fBMin;
    end else
    if V > fBMin then begin
      V:= V - fBStep;
    end else
    if V < fBMin then begin
      V:= V + fBStep;
    end;
    fBalls[X]:= V;
  end;
end;

//This timer draws the balls
procedure TForm1.tmrDrawTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;   //Loop counter
  V: Integer;   //Value of individual ball intensity
  C: Integer;   //Count of balls
  R: TRect;     //Rect of individual ball
  Z: Integer;   //Size of each ball
  Col: TColor;  //Color to draw each ball
  B: TBitmap;
begin
  B:= TBitmap.Create;
  try
    B.Width:= Img.ClientWidth;
    B.Height:= Img.ClientHeight;
    C:= Length(fBalls);
    Z:= Img.Height;
    R:= Rect(0, 0, Z, Z);
    B.TransparentColor:= clWhite;
    B.Transparent:= True;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
    B.Canvas.Pen.Style:= psClear;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clWhite;
    B.Canvas.FillRect(B.Canvas.ClipRect);
    for X:= 0 to C - 1 do begin
      V:= fBalls[X];
      Col:= ColorBetween(fCMin, fCMax, (V / fBMax)*100);
      B.Canvas.Brush.Color:= Col;
      B.Canvas.Ellipse(R);
      R.Left:= R.Left + Z;
      R.Right:= R.Right + Z;
    end;
    Img.Picture.Assign(B);
  finally
    B.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  fDir:= 1;
  fPos:= 0;
  fBMin:= 0;
  fBMax:= 100;
  fBallCount:= 40;
  fBStep:= 8;
  fCMin:= clNavy;
  fCMax:= clSkyBlue;
  SetLength(fBalls, fBallCount);
  for X:= 0 to Length(fBalls) - 1 do
    fBalls[X]:= fBMin;
  tmrDraw.Enabled:= True;
  tmrBalls.Enabled:= True;
  tmrChase.Enabled:= True;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmrChaseTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fPos:= fPos + fDir;
  if (fPos >= fBallCount) then begin
    fDir:= -1;
  end;
  if (fPos <= 0) then begin
    fDir:= 1;
  end;
  fBalls[fPos]:= fBMax;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  tmrDraw.Enabled:= False;
  tmrBalls.Enabled:= False;
  tmrChase.Enabled:= False;
end;

end.
```

This is the CPU window (don't know if it will help) as the exception is first raised:

[image: CPU window on exception]

And the call stack is empty:

[image: Call stack empty]

**EDIT:** This problem has been solved. The issue (as seen in the answers below) was writing to an index of an array which was not allocated (I was missing `- 1` after `Length(MyArray)`). Here's a picture of the final product (with two balls chasing back and forth in opposite directions):

[image: Final product]

Comment: fwiw, I can't reproduce this using Delphi 2010 on a Windows XP machine. Perhaps it's time to upgrade ;)

Comment: Did you try when the movement is from right to left? When it's moving from left to right, I have no problem at all.

Comment: I tried several runs. 1) Moving from left to right. 2) LRL. 3) LRLR. 4) LRLRL. 5) LRLRL (again).

Comment: Just to make sure, `Notify on language exceptions` is enabled?

Comment: Just tried on my colleague's D2010 and sure enough, no issues. Problem is, I am extremely comfortable with D7, and have actually downgraded many apps from 2010 to 7.

Comment: what about breaking on language exceptions? Is it enabled?

Comment: I cannot find this option `Notify on language exceptions` in D7 - I'm sure you're right.

Comment: Take a look at [Stop on Delphi Exceptions](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32015) under Debugger Options, the Language Exceptions tab.

Comment: OK, I changed the option - but now i still get the errors, just Delphi doesn't stop before the exception (traditionally you would see 2 errors for each exception in debug mode). So that did solve half the problem, just not all of it.

Comment: I assumed it *didn't* break at first, as you mentioned you didn't get a breakpoint in the code. My suggestion was to turn it on <g>. After turning it back on, could you verify you enabled [use debug dcu's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136101/how-to-step-into-rtl-vcl-using-delphi-7)?

Comment: Hmmm strange, enabled `Use debug dcu's` and now it does take me to a breakpoint - in system.pas... line 2477 in function _Freemem specifically at `if Result <> 0 then Error(reInvalidPtr);`

Comment: at this point, you should be able to view the call stack and look at what method(s) lead to the error. I encourage you to append the call stack window to your post.

Comment: Not sure how to get you this and/or at what point to give you this. If I pause the application just after the exception (to see the CPU window) is this what you mean? FYI: exception occurs after the `OnClose` event has been called (thus after all 3 timers have been disabled).

Comment: You can view the call stack window with CTRL-ALT-S or CTRL-SHIFT-S keyboard shortcut I believe. If not, you should be able to find it in one of the Delphi IDE menu's *(I've shut down my development machine)*.

Comment: It seems to occur after `Application.Run` has been exited (After application is terminated) in the project's unit. I traced it all the way into `until Terminated` in the Forms.TApplication.Run procedure - after that, the exception appears.

Comment: Call Stack window is empty - looks like a list with nothing listed.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what to make of that but as a last resort, I would recommend installing a tool like madExcept (or EurekaLog) into your IDE, enable it for your project, run it and post the results back. I would be interested in a printscreen from the CPU window to (one never knows).

Comment: ok I just put the CPU screen and call stack SS above.

Comment: do you have any finalization methods in any of the units in the project?

Comment: Nope, actually already thought of that, you're looking at the only unit in the project (besides the project its self). Everything is pure VCL, nothing custom.

Comment: A minor comment on the code. Having a field `fBallCount` in addition to `fBalls` is dangerous. You run the risk of `fBallCount` getting out of sync with the array. Get rig of `fBallCount` and use `Length(fBalls)` instead. Even better, wrap `Length(fBalls)` in a property called `BallCount` for better encapsulation.

Comment: I understand your point clearly, and actually deliberately did this. The idea is that during one drawing session (tmrDrawTimer) it shall strictly read Length(fBalls). However, fBallCount is subject to change at any moment, and shall not conflict with the already in-progress drawing. In this way, just as I start drawing, I can read fBallCount and set the array size as the drawing starts. If it's in the middle of drawing and I set the size of fBalls, it could cause even worse problems.

Comment: (That is, keeping in mind that I will be moving each of these 3 timers into threads when I'm ready)

Comment: Threads in timers won't help since you are performing UI which all needs to be in the main thread.

Comment: Well I'm not putting threads in timers - timers are my `temporary thread` for development. There will be in the end 1 thread (and no timers) which takes care of this whole processes, using a DC to get a canvas inside the thread to draw to. This is actually related to my other question about threads inside of a DLL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried this on Delphi 6, and had the same problem. After a bit of tracing I discovered the error was occurring when releasing the FBalls dynamic array,

This error occurred in the old Delphi memory manager, and changing to [FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) resolved it - but that is a bit of a hack. It may also explain why the problem doesn't affect older versions of Delphi.

Even using SetLength(FBalls, 0) in form close produced this error.

### EDIT - ROOT CAUSE

This made me suspicious about the array handling, and I then noticed an error in `tmrChaseTimer`, that cause it to write outside the array bounds. I added some checking to this, and everything works OK:

```
procedure TForm1.tmrChaseTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fPos:= fPos + fDir;
  if (fPos >= fBallCount) then begin
    fDir:= -1;
  end;
  if (fPos <= 0) then begin
    fDir:= 1;
  end;
  if (fPos >= 0) and (fPos < fBallCount) then // <-- prevent writing outside array bounds
    fBalls[fPos]:= fBMax;
end;
```

I retied the code with Range checking turned on, and it immediately threw an error:

---

### Debugger Exception Notification

### Project Project1.exe raised exception class ERangeError with message 'Range check error'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

### OK   Help

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: +1 Thanks for chiming in Gerry, I was clean out of suggestions.

Comment: If this is the case, then its no wonder it works in D2010 and not in D7. So it seems like a Delphi 7 bug in other words?

Comment: Changed `TBallStates` to `PBallStates` (made a pointer type for it) and used that instead (of course with `fBalls:= New(PBallStates);` and `Dispose(fBalls);`) as necessary, as well as using ^, and no different. I was hoping manual management of the array would help, but it didn't.

Comment: See the updated answer - I have determined the probable root cause as a mistake in the array handling leading to memory corruption. In this specific case the old memory manager happened to fail, and FastMM4 worked, but different corruption could have the opposite effect.

Comment: Bingo! Indeed, I did not think that would be the problem, I assume it should have raised an exception earlier (when fPos exceeds Length(fBalls)), not after the app is closed.

Comment: @Jerry No, the bug is in your code, in `tmrChaseTimer`, where you blatently write to the array out-of-bounds. If you would just switch on range checking then the compiler would have told you this the first time you ran the code. Please please please use range checking.

Comment: Well with range checking turned on now, and with the fix as Gerry posted, I no longer have this problem. Gerry, does it take you to a breakpoint?